# I don't understand how this dotted line appeared around this object in Adobe Illustrator, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I don't even know what it is or how it got there.

[image]

Comment: Hey Blaine, welcome to GDSE. It's really hard to understand your issue without knowing more context. If you could please update to include more info, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I wish I knew what it was, or how it got there. Maybe I pressed a key on accident? I really don't know. If I knew what this dotted line was called, I could probably just Google it and turn it off, but I don't know what it is, or what it's called. If I knew what it was called, I wouldn't need to ask, I could just Google it.

Comment: When I search Google for "strange dotted line in adobe illustrator" I get about a million results, some saying "learn how to make a dotted line" and so forth... so my search queries aren't answering my question. You are my only hope stack exchange...

Comment: It seems to be some kind of "guide" or something. It's not an actual "object." I simply have no clue what it is or how it got there, I think I just hit a key on accident or did something and there it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checked 'Draw inside'.

You must check 'Draw Normal' instead.

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to switch the three modes.

[image]

Comment: awesome, thank you